# Why doesn't SwiftUI reflect a @State property value in a toolbar Menu?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Testing this piece of code with Xcode 14 beta 5. Everything is working properly (sorting items with an animation, plus saving the selected `sortOrder` in `UserDefaults`).

However the `if-else` condition in the `Menu`'s label seems to be ignored and the label is not updated. Please do you know why? Or what is alternate solution to avoid this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum SortOrder: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
        case forward
        case reverse
        
        var id: Self {
            self
        }
        
        static let `default`: Self = .forward
        
        var label: String {
            switch self {
            case .forward: return "Sort (forward)"
            case .reverse: return "Sort (reverse)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    @AppStorage("sortOrder") var sortOrder: SortOrder = .default {
        didSet {
            sort()
        }
    }
    
    
    @State private var items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    var toolbar: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem {
            Menu {
                ForEach(SortOrder.allCases) { sortOrder in
                    Button {
                        withAnimation { self.sortOrder = sortOrder }
                    } label: {
                        // FIXME: doesn't reflect sortOrder value
                        if sortOrder == self.sortOrder {
                            Label(sortOrder.label, systemImage: "checkmark")
                        } else {
                            Text(sortOrder.label)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Actions", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .toolbar { toolbar }
            .onAppear(perform: sort)
        }
    }
    
    func sort() {
        switch sortOrder {
        case .forward:
            items.sort(by: <)
        case .reverse:
            items.sort(by: >)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to use a `Picker` with `.pickerStyle` modifier set to `.menu`, instead of a hardcoded `Menu`.

```
var toolbar: some ToolbarContent {
    ToolbarItem {
        Picker(selection: $selectedSort) {
            ForEach(Sort.allCases) { sort in
                Text(sort.localizedTitle).tag(sort)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Sort by", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
        }
        .pickerStyle(.menu)
    }
}
```

Now SwiftUI automatically updates the interface.

Answer (score 2):

It is selected but `Menu` is not updated, assuming in toolbar it should be persistent.

A possible workaround is to force-rebuild menu on sort change, like

```
Menu {

   // ...

} label: {
    Label("Actions", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
}
.id(self.sortOrder)  // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 14b5 / iOS 16

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question: do you think this is the normal behavior or is it a bug (and therefore should I remove this fix in a future version)?

Comment: I submitted it as a bug FB11031492 on 3rd August 2022 and the current status is Recent Similar Reports: less than 10, Resolution: Potential fix identified - in iOS 16.

Comment: Just ran my test project and seems fixed - Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b)

Answer (score 0):

The `if-else` in your `ToolbarItem` is working correctly. The problem here is that `.labelStyle` in a toolbar are defaulted to `.titleOnly`.

To display the label with both icon and title, you would need to add `.labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)`.

Comment: The condition is not working. If the `label` closure is replaced with `Text("\(sortOrder.rawValue) / selection: \(self.sortOrder.rawValue)")`, then when running the simulator, this `Text` is never updated.